# How can I configure nodejs rollup in bazel a workspace with multiple npm packages?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules-nodejs

I am trying to sort out how to correctly use `rollup_bundle()` in bazel in a workspace using multiple languages, including JavaScript, and defining multiple npm packages in different directories.

It appears that the rollup bazel rules assume a more centralized setup than I would like: in the context of this workspace I would like each npm package to manage its own `node_modules` (see `WORKSPACE.bazel` in reproducible).

Small reproducible (toy example):

https://github.com/mdittmer/bazel-nodejs-rollup-multi-package/commit/a14408c083836ae024719e540ee1115e61eabc97

```
$ bazel build //js/alpha
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: /path/to/bazel-nodejs-rollup-multi-package/js/alpha/BUILD.bazel:6:14: every rule of type rollup_bundle implicitly depends upon the target '//@bazel/rollup/bin:rollup-worker', but this target could not be found because of: no such package '@bazel/rollup/bin': BUILD file not found in any of the following directories. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package.
 - /path/to/bazel-nodejs-rollup-multi-package/@bazel/rollup/bin
Documentation for implicit attribute rollup_worker_bin of rules of type rollup_bundle:
Internal use only
ERROR: Analysis of target '//js/alpha:alpha' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.363s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (4 packages loaded, 5 targets configured)
    currently loading: @rules_nodejs//nodejs/stamp
```

This error seems to suggest that I may need to specify `rollup_bin` and/or `rollup_worker_bin`, but I have had no luck attempting to refer to sources in `//js/alpha/node_modules/@bazel/...` or `//js/alpha/node_modules/rollup/...`. [The npm documentation for @bazel/rollup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bazel/rollup) suggests that because I am using `npm_install()` to set up my in-tree npm packages I should not need to set `rollup_bin` (because related instructions begin with "If you didn't use the `yarn_install` or `npm_install` rule, [...]").

How do I keep my multiple-npm-packages-in-same-workspace setup while using bazel rules to run rollup?

Answer (score 1):

I posted a viable solution here:

https://github.com/mdittmer/bazel-nodejs-rollup-multi-package/commit/07c0810a7e2d4185311f4bab4f36555648585b97

The issue appears to stem from the `@build_bazel_rules_nodejs` rules hard-coding `@npm//...` dependencies, i.e., they assume that the correct repository for loading npm module dependencies must be named `@npm`. To get multiple notions of `@npm` (theoretically--I only bothered to remap one such repository), I declared a local repository in the root `//WORKSPACE.bazel` file:

`//WORKSPACE.bazel`:

```
npm_install(
  name = "npm_alpha",
  package_json = "@alpha//:package.json",
  package_lock_json = "@alpha//:package-lock.json",
)

local_repository(
  name = "alpha",
  path = "js/alpha",
  repo_mapping = {
    "@npm": "@npm_alpha",
  },
)
```

The `repo_mapping` maps my choice of repository to the name `@npm` in the `@alpha` repository. Presumably, repeating this with similarly configured `@beta` and `@npm_beta` repositories will achieve the desired configuration across multiple npm modules. In this setup the root `//WORKSPACE.bazel` does most of the "heavy lifting" and `//js/alpha/WORKSPACE.bazel` is practically empty.

*Aside*: It appears that re-defining `@npm` with the configuration up to and including the `npm_install()` with appropriately renamed `name`, `package_json`, and `package_lock_json` in `//js/alpha/WORKSPACE.bazel` does not interfere with the root repository working as intended and has the side benefit of the `//js/alpha` repository working correctly as a root repository if desired.

**One unresolved issue** I was surprised to encounter was this:

https://github.com/mdittmer/bazel-nodejs-rollup-multi-package/commit/c2bde0fc02bce8f4b1b42dc5881a4f9bc26186db

switching from `npm_install()` to `yarn_install()` did not work (see commit message in linked commit for details).

Comment: Filed https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/issues/3424 to track "One unresolved issue".